# Passing parameters to react native onPress event, app freezes, or data is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am kind of stuck with it, I just can't get it working properly, I've found couple of stack overflow links too, it seems that syntax is correct.

setEvent gets parameters, this version will freeze the app, if I destruct or send only couple of fields from object, it will say, that those are undefined.

Any help, I would be happy, can't figure out the mistake myself.

Line, that should send data `<TouchableOpacity onPress={(item) => this.setEvent(item)}>`

one item is just one object with properties id and name.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {server, defaultRequestSettings} from "../configuration";
import {styles} from '../styles/home_screen';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

state = {
    loading: true
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setEvent = this.setEvent.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${server}/data`, defaultRequestSettings)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                dataSource: responseJson.events,
            });
        });
}

setEvent (item) {
    console.log(item)
};

render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
                <ActivityIndicator/>
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.dataSource}
                renderItem={({item}) =>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={(item) => this.setEvent(item)}>
                        <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
                keyExtractor={({id}) => `list-item-${id}`}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your state like this in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: [],
    }
    this.setEvent = this.setEvent.bind(this);
}
```

in this way initial state of dataSource would be an empty array, you also should use [lodash](https://lodash.com/), which would further save you from undefined response from server like this

```
import _ from 'lodash'

const dataSource = _.get(this.state, 'dataSource', [])
```

**UPDATE**

remove item from onPress like this

```
onPress={() => this.setEvent(item)
```

because it takes item as a callback object which is returned by the TouchableOpacity instead you need the object from FlatList.

Comment: The data, that's coming from server is fine, everything works, except the onPress event data forwarding.

Comment: that is defined under componentDidMount, just one console.log :)

Comment: why are you doing this this.setEvent = this.setEvent.bind(this); ?

Comment: This way your event handler has its context bound to the component instance. You can access props and state and call setState or forceUpdate, etc. from such bound handler. and that has nothing to do with the freezing app with no errors :)

Comment: as of ES6 you don't need to do this and remove 'item' from onPress because it takes item as a callback object which is returned by the Component, Simply do this onPress={() => this.setEvent(item)

Comment: Thank You so much, can you post it as an answer, i will mark it, this solution works, it logs the correct data now, i dont understand the freezing app part with 0 errors

Comment: Updated the answer.